# How do I solve the following integration?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

[image]

The integral gives probability distribution of $M$, and $M$ is the absolute value of the  sum of two random variates both following $P(\mu)$ distribution.

Comment: What is the range of $M$?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: since $M=|\mu_1+\mu_2|$, and both $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ lie in [-1,1], M lies in [0,2]

Comment: I think you want to give open interval (-1,1)

Comment: Yeah you are right. Anyway,actual problem still remains.